# Some online video/audio will not play

Tags: sound, firefox, video

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  and I can get videos to play with sound on YouTube but all Facebook videos will not play or no sound.  SiriusXM loads and plays but still no sound.  I have checked and double checked everything, all volume controls are on.  I am using the most current Mozilla Firefox.  Its a THINK PENGUIN computer, basic model.  I am lost as to what to do to get the Facebook Videos to play or how I can hear my SiriusXM radio?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Does chrome browser act the same?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Firefox, or the whole computer for that matter?

Comment: This is a Facebook issue. Refer to Facebook, not here.

Answer (score 1):

From Firefox's media codec support table:

> To avoid patent issues, support for MPEG 4, H.264 and MP3 is not built
>   directly into Firefox. Instead it relies on support from the OS or
>   hardware (the hardware also needs to be able to support the profile
>   used to encode the video, in the case of MP4). ... Linux since Firefox
>   26.0 (relies on GStreamer codecs) ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

From GStreamers plugin lists:

> gst-plugins-ugly
>
> > lame — Encode MP3s with LAME
> >
> > x264 — libx264-based H264 plugins

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins/html/ch02.html

Ubuntu:

> patent and copyright restrictions (see Ubuntu License Policy)
>   complicate distribution of software to support non-free formats. ...
>   However, you can install the ability to play popular non-free media
>   formats ... by following the instructions below.
>
> ...
>
> **Legal Notice** Patent and copyright laws operate differently depending
>   on which country you are in. Please obtain legal advice if you are
>   unsure whether a particular patent or restriction applies to a media
>   format you wish to use in your country.
>
> ...
>
> #### Manual Install
>
> If you are using regular, stock Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
> ```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: P.S. Blame Apple for this. That is all.